# regex to truncate second field separated by space

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex to truncate 2nd field. I have written one regex but its not working in all cases.

**data:**

```
qcst_macroPlayback.sh -play qcstTools/qcstOutFiles/qcst_out_macroPlayback_20500_12102017-131013.5574.xml
qcst_runningProcessesDetails.sh -LS
qcst_coreGrabber.sh DIR1
```

**Output Should be:**

```
-play
-LS
DIR1
```

**myregex:**

```
^\S+_[^\.]+.sh(?<ScriptName2> [^\.]+ )
```

**Link to Test regex**
https://regex101.com/r/P0Rnku/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^\S+_\S+\.sh\s+(?<ScriptName2>\S+)
```

Or, if the `_` presence is not necessary to check for, shorten it to

```
^\S+\.sh\s+(?<ScriptName2>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8IuIi1/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (with `m` option, start of a line)
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespaces (if you want to make sure there is only 1 `_` here, replace this and the next `\S+` with `[^\s_]+` or `[^\s_]*` depending on the requirements)
- `_` - there must be at least 1 `_`
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespaces
- `\.sh` - a `.sh` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<ScriptName2>\S+)` - group "ScriptName2": 1 or more non-whitespaces

Comment: made little shorter : "^\S+\.sh\s*(?<ScriptName2>\S+)"

Comment: @AnkitGoyal I do not know your exact requirements. If the `_` is not necessary to check in the `*.sh` substring, yes, just `\S+` is enough.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. but  forget to mention one more thing some time 2nd field is not present in that case it should not extract anything

Comment: What is the requirement for the 2nd field? Please provide an example. Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/8IuIi1/3), it does not match anything if there is just 1 non-whitespace chunk.

Comment: @AnkitGoyal That is just a bunch of lines in the input at regex101. In real life, are you going to pass the lines as separate strings or as a single multiline string? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/P0Rnku/3), this is what you will get if you pass the lines separately (the `\h` only matches horizontal whitespaces).

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew: Actually, It's working. in few cases its doen't work but its not because of regex. its issue in my raw data. Thanks a million :)